# Regex to allow only particular numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a field which should only take values divisible of 12. Such as `12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120.` 
I used below regex :

```
12|24|36|48|60|72|84|96|108|120
```

But this also allows values such as `12abc, 12-!&`. It's allowing alphabets or special characters with the numbers.
Is there any regex to only allow `12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120` as input.

Comment: This is not a job for a regex.

Comment: if you only need those specific numbers you could put a start and end char to the regex `^(12|24|36|48|60|72|84|96|108|120)$`, but in general I think @Pointy is right.

Comment: function isValid (input){
       return (input % 12 === 0) && (input>11) && (input<121);
    }

    function doingStuffWithInput(input) {
       if (isValid(input)){
         //do stuff
       } else{
         alert("error, not valid");
       }

If you wish to do it without regex

Comment: This page about anchors might be helpful https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html

Comment: @Onheiron thanks it worked

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Pointy that this doesn't sound like a job for regex. If you're using HTML5 input validation, definitely go for [the approach Sean T shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57432840/157247).

But from what you've said it's matching, it's just that you don't have start-of-input (`^`) and end-of-input anchors (`$`):

```
^(?:12|24|36|48|60|72|84|96|108|120)$
```

(You need the non-capturing group or the anchors become part of the alternative they're next to.)

If you want to allow harmless spaces:

```
^\s*(?:12|24|36|48|60|72|84|96|108|120)\s*$
```

---

Obviously in either case (doing something like this or Sean's HTML5 approach), if this is being sent to a server, you need to validate it on the server as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using html5 controls use `step`, `min` and `max`.

```
<input type="number" step="12" min="0" max="120" name="multiplesOfTwelve"/>
```

Comment: Probably also `min=0` or `min=12`

Comment: You'd still need server-side validation ( and that should not be regex-based ) to filter for fabricated POST requests.

Comment: @collapsar They've not specified what server side framework they're using so it's hard for me to state that :)

Comment: @collapsar - Well, that's a truism, not really a specific to Sean's answer. :-) **No** client-side validation is sufficient on its own.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right. The Q however only asks for (regex-based) validation in general which would include client- and server-side, while this answer is limited to the client.

Comment: @collapsar doing validation on the server in almost any likely framework/language would also not be wise with a regex. It's a simple math problem.

Comment: @Pointy: Agreed, absolutely!